# Distinguish between 0-string and non-0-string

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

We all know how to convert from string to number i.e.:

```
int str2num(const string& str) 
{
   stringstream is(str);
   int result;
   return is >> result ? result : 0;
};
```

My question I want to be able to distinguish when the string can't be converted to number but is not 0 ex.:

```
1.) "0" => 0
2.) "0dasd" => 0
3.) "" => 0
4.) "some string" => 0 but true
5.) "345" => 345
```

I want to be able to detect case (4).
The only idea I have is to lookup the string `!! .find()` or something..
Does stringstream has some way of indicating this situation ?

---

EDIT: Some clarification:
As the `num2str()` function I'm ok when conversation fails and/or returns `0`, the function also to `return 0` i.e. `(cases:1,2,3,4)`.
But then in the `case 4`, I want to able to detect it inside the function, so that like you said throw an `err`... or return out-of-band data using pair<> or out-variable.

Or to be even more clear I want to detect :

if `is >> num returns 0 (ex:"0","0.0","000", "0sad","asd0ss")` is it really ZERO or it is string-that-is-not-convertable to number I.E. distinguish between 0-string and non-0-string

PS>
My confusion probably also arise, because I'm unsure which cases of 0-in-a-string are interpreted as 0-num or just-string when converted.
Did I confuse even more :) or it is more clear now?
I want to implement something along the lines of Perl zero-but-true semantic.

---

EDIT2: Thank you for all the examples of how to exactly return out-of-bound data, I really appreciate them..I mean really..
(I will probably use pair<>, dont want to use boost or `C++11` semantics yet).
But I was more interested of "what stringstream think is `0-string` and `non-0-string` and how to detect the difference?

Comment: By cannot be converted to number you mean a string with no digits in it? Because to me it seems case 2 is equivalent to case 4.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to test whether you converted something successfully. Distinguishing between your third and fourth cases is going to be a bit more difficult though -- treating "no input to convert" as "successfully converted something" doesn't seem (to me) to make much sense though. If you can live with treating case 3 and 4 as unsuccessful conversions and the rest as successful, it's pretty easy: just test the state of the stream after the attempted conversion:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){ 
    char const *inputs[] = { "0", "0dasd", "", "some string", "345"};

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        std::istringstream buf(inputs[i]);
        int val;

        if (buf>>val) 
            std::cout << "Converted : \"" << inputs[i] << "\" To: " << val << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Could not convert: \"" << inputs[i] << "\" To int\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which produces:

```
Converted : "0" To: 0
Converted : "0dasd" To: 0
Could not convert: "" To int
Could not convert: "some string" To int
Converted : "345" To: 345
```

If you really want to treat case 3 as successful as well, I guess it wouldn't take a lot to add some special treatment for an empty string as always converting successfully.

Comment: Now that you know whether the conversion was good or not, the question is how to make this information useful.  You could throw an exception for a failed conversions as some languages do it, or you could return a more complex answer like `std::pair<int, bool>` (or use an enum instead of bool for more detailed answers).

Comment: Your assignment of `char*` to a string literal makes me feel bad.

Comment: @DeadMG: I hate to see a puppy in pain. Hopefully it's better now.

Comment: Actually, the excruciating stomach pain wasn't from your answer, but it didn't help either :P

Answer (score 2):

Your string conversion function is bad and you should feel bad.

```
template<typename F> int str2num(const string& str, F&& f) {
   stringstream is(str);
   int result;
   if (is >> result) return result;
   return f();
}
int str2num(const string& str) {
    return str2num(str, [] -> int {
        throw std::runtime_error("Parse failure!");
    });
}
int str2num(const string& str, int def) {
    return str2num(str, [=] {
        return def;
    });
}
```

Your choice of 0 as a magic default value is bad- perhaps 32 is a sane default for someone who wants to try to parse an integer. 0 could also be a meaningful value separate from parse failure. If you want a default, you need the user to explicitly specify such, because your random I/O function has *no idea* what a meaningful default might be.

If the user does not provide an explicit error-handling strategy, either in the form of an error handling function or a meaningful default value, then throwing an exception is the only way to go.

Comment: it was to illustrate the example. thanks for example you provided... is there emoticon for "feel bad"

Comment: The point isn't that 0 isn't a sane default, it's that *you can't possibly know what the default should be*.

Comment: you are correct..i used this ver. so i can develop some stuff first.. before I needed zero-but-true semantics

Answer (score 1):

You need to return two bits of information: One integer with the conversion result, and one flag indicating success or otherwise. The error condition could also be handled by throwing an exception, but generally external data is never "exceptional", and parsing errors should be treated as normal control flow, not an exception.

The result would look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
boost::optional<int> parse_as(std::string const & s)
{
    if (s.empty()) { return T(); }

    T result;

    return std::istringstream(s) >> result ? result : boost::none;
}
```

Usage: `auto n = parse_as<int>(str);`, and test if the result is set.

---

Alternative token extraction that requires that the entire string match:

```
std::istringstream iss(s);

return iss >> result >> std::ws && iss.get() == EOF ? result : boost::none;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you want to signal the result: The extraction functions set the stream to a bad state if they fail to do the conversion. The conversion fails for integers if no digit could be exteacted. That is, it seems you have three case:

1. The string is `empty()` and you return `0`.
2. The conversion is successful and you return the vale.
3. The conversion fails and you do something to indicate the failure, e.g., you throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who commented.
Here is what I had in mind :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;
#define pBool std::pair<bool,int>

pBool str2num(const string& str) {
    istringstream is(str);
    pBool rv(false,0);
    if (str == "0E0") {//Zero but true
        rv = std::make_pair(true,0);
    } else {
        is >> rv.second;//convert
        //cout << "fail?:" << is.fail() << endl;
        //logical XOR : !fail != !0?
        if ( !is.fail() != (rv.second == 0) ) rv.first = true;
//      if (!is.fail() && rv.second != 0) rv.first = true;//successful conversion
//      if (is.fail() && rv.second == 0) rv.first = true;
    };
    return rv;
};

template<class T>
void dump_pair(T& p) {
    cout << "Bool:" << p.first << endl;
    cout << "Val :" << p.second << endl;
}

int main() {

    cout << ">>0E0" << endl;
    pBool rv1 = str2num("0E0");
    dump_pair(rv1);

    cout << ">>0" << endl;
    pBool rv2 = str2num("0");
    dump_pair(rv2);

    cout << ">>0.0dsad" << endl;
    pBool rv3 = str2num("0dsad");
    dump_pair(rv3);

    cout << ">>456ttt" << endl;
    pBool rv4 = str2num("456ttt");
    dump_pair(rv4);

    cout << ">>adttt" << endl;
    pBool rv5 = str2num("ad555ttt");
    dump_pair(rv5);

    return 0;
}

====OUTPUT====
>>0E0
Bool:1
Val :0
>>0
Bool:0
Val :0
>>0.0dsad
Bool:0
Val :0
>>456ttt
Bool:1
Val :456
>>adttt
Bool:1
Val :0
```